# swagger, Spring, Spring boot

Tags: spring, swagger

I have a Spring boot application . The endpoint gets listed on Swagger Ui. However the Authorize Button is not showing up. I am using Swagger core version 1.5.* . What version of swagger ui do I need for this. I have added @SwaggerDefinition annotation to the code but that is not helping.

Comment: Please post your Swagger configuration with the relevant annotations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SWAGGER version above 2.0 [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/authentication/) you can find how you can add authentication in your application.